# What would be powershell version from this c# code?

Tags: powershell

What would be powershell version of this c# code? I am having hard time get this work in Powershell especially stringbuilder and files.add line where utf8encoding is. Here is my powershell version of the code. http://wikisend.com/download/429800/Add_Files_PS.txt. Here is the error.

> ```
> Missing expression after ','.
> At C:\PowerShell\Add_Item.ps1:60 char:73
> +         $newFile = $docLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($newDestinationFolderPath, <<<<
> UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()), $true)
>     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (,:String) [], ParseException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
> ```

```
using ( SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite( "http://moss.litwareinc.com" ) ) {
    using ( SPWeb web = siteCollection.OpenWeb( "docs" ) ) {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Sample"];

        //link to the file
        string fileLinkUrl = "http://moss.litwareinc.com/docs/Shared%20Documents/ConfigureIRMinWSS30.doc";

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        using ( TextReader reader = new StreamReader( @"C:\linktodocumenttemplate.txt" ) ) {
            builder.Append( reader.ReadToEnd() );
        }

        //replace string template with values
        builder.Replace( "{0}", fileLinkUrl );

        //should change the name of the .aspx file per item
        SPFile file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add( "link_title.aspx", UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString()));

        //set list item properties
        SPListItem item = file.Item;
        item["Content Type"] = "Link to a Document";
        SPFieldUrlValue itemUrl = new SPFieldUrlValue();
        itemUrl.Description = "From sample code";
        itemUrl.Url = fileLinkUrl;
        item["URL"] = itemUrl;
        //persist changes
        item.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The builder part you can implement using

```
 $content = (Get-Content 'C:\linktodocumenttemplate.txt') -replace '\{0}', $filelinkurl
```

The UTF8 part you can implement using

```
$utf8 = New-Object -Type "System.Text.UTF8Encoding"
$bytes = $utf8.GetBytes($content)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
What error message you get while running your C# code? I have tested [this sample code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cliffgreen/archive/2008/06/23/creating-a-link-to-a-document-item-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically.aspx) and it works fine for me.

In any case, you can Run/test your C# code using PowerShell, which means your existing C# code could be reused inside Powershell without a need to implement it as Cmdlet.

Technet sample: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that. http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/sharepoint-document-library-add.html

Comment: I already converted the code into powershell but having trouble files.add line. I think i need to convert utf8 ... to ps friendly.

Comment: it seems that you have copied the code from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cliffgreen/archive/2008/06/23/creating-a-link-to-a-document-item-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-programmatically.aspx. Have your created a site and document library as suggested in the code, or changed your parameters?

Comment: Could you please post the error message?

Comment: I uploaded the code in a txt file. http://wikisend.com/download/429800/Add_Files_PS.txt

Answer (score 0):

This may work:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/05/31/how-we-can-create-documents-inside-a-document-library-based-upon-our-content-type-s-document-template.aspx

Powershell:

```
$oFile = $DocLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add("TestDoc1.aspx", oWeb.GetFile(oContentType .DocumentTemplateUrl).OpenBinary(), true);
```

Comment: I am getting error on $eb.GetFile
Exception calling "GetFile" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."
At C:\PowerShell\Add_Item.ps1:65 char:86
+         $file = $spLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add($filewithpath, $web.GetFile <<<< ($ct.DocumentT
emplateUrl).OpenBinary(), $true)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: I put the whole path to getfile method get one more error message in addition to the above error. What the Hell? Microsoft has NO good documentation on this.

Exception calling "OpenBinary" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot open file "_layout/newlink.aspx"."
At C:\PS\Add_Item.ps1:70 char:40
+                 $binFile = $spf.OpenBinary <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: This works with some caveat. I downloaded the newlink.aspx file then uploaded to a document library say "templates". then it works. But iconUrl is not same when loading files.